# System.Argument Exception Error in vb.net, My Code is below

Tags: vb.net

here is my code

```vb
For Each Cel As DataGridViewCell In GridRow.Cells
    If Cel.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Cel.Value.ToString(),
                              Cel.InheritedStyle.Font,
                              New SolidBrush(Cel.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                              New RectangleF(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)),
                                             CSng(iTopMargin),
                                             CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)),
                                             CSng(iCellHeight)),
                              strFormat)
    End If

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,
                             New Rectangle(CInt(arrColumnLefts(iCount)),
                                           iTopMargin,
                                           CInt(arrColumnWidths(iCount)),
                                           iCellHeight))
    iCount += 1
Next
```

Comment: What event is this code in?

Comment: Maybe `InheritedStyle` is null/Nothing. Use the `Cel.Style` instead if so. Use your debugger.

Comment: As suggested, you need to use your debugger, in the `DrawString` method you have five arguments and then two of those are constructors with arguments too. How about you separate out the creation of the `SolidBrush` and the `RectangleF` to see whether it's one of those constructor arguments that's the issue? You've provided us with the exception type but none of the other information it provides, particularly the error message. You haven't done all you can to get all the relevant information and then pass that on to us.

Comment: The exception details should tell you what you're doing wrong.  I believe `ArgumentException` has a field for the name of the argument that has an issue, and the message should be descriptive as well.